# Why the broadcast receiver doesn't work in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I start a service to listen the change in clipboard.
If the clipboard has the right string that i need,then the service send the broadcast.

```
    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    cm.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
            ClipData.Item item = cm.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
            // Gets the clipboard as text.
            pasteData = (String) item.getText();
            if (pasteData.equals("SE123456")){
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.setAction("HAS_STUDENT_RECORD");
                intent.putExtra("clipboard",pasteData);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        }
    });
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

The broadcast than start the activity.

```
public class StudentRecordBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String action="HAS_STUDENT_RECORD";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
    if (intent.getAction().equals(action)){
        Intent intent12=new Intent(context,ActivityStudent.class);
        intent12.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent12);
    }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

But when i copy the string into the clipboard,the activity doesn't show.However,It make a Toast,but i don't know where the Toast came from.
[image]

I don't know the reason.

Comment: All right,i change the pictures into codes

Comment: You cannot start an activity from the background on modern versions of Android. Also, modern versions of Android will show a `Toast` for some clipboard operations.

Comment: I understand ，thank you.But how can I show a page/start an activity through the broadcast receicer?

Comment: "But how can I show a page/start an activity through the broadcast receicer?" -- that is not possible in general on modern versions of Android. Please raise a `Notification` instead.